# How to return value from a void method that extend from a superclass

Tags: java

As I want to use some fields in a void method that extend from superclass. I tried to change the type from void to int, but no surprise, compiled error! It show "The return type is incompatible with ...."
How can return something from the method in a situation that I can't change the superclass?

Comment: You can't override a method and change it's signature. *"How can return something from the method in a situation that I can't change the superclass?"* - how do you expect a return value from a `void` method?

Comment: "As I want to use some fields in a void method that extend from superclass". Fields in a method are encapsulated. You can not use them as they are only local variables.

Comment: Didn't see the line quoted by @peeskillet. So, why do you need to access a local var in a method? Can you please edit the question and tell us what you're trying to acheive?

Comment: You should really show some code. It will help us better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks all! As a junior, I am playing robocode with class JuniorRobot. But it has limitation that can't return anything from buildin method.Anyway, just a game. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of the key rules when overriding methods: you can't change the return type, unless it's a supertype of the return type declared in the superclass. But, definitely, that has nothing to do with void methods.